# methods from .pyc file not being read

Tags: python, pyc

I have a python file that does something. It calls into methods from a .pyc file as follows.

someFile.py

```
# do something 

from EvaluateT.read_input_data import *
print "imported"

# do something 

inputData = ReadInputData(someInputFile)
print "read"

# do something
```

When I call the interpreter and type the following statements,

```
import read_input_data
help (read_input_data)
```

I see the following output:

```
CLASSES
     ReadInputData

class ReadInputData
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, inputFile)
 |  
 |  read_input_data(self)
```

But, when I run someFile.py, the output prints 'imported' and ignores everything after the 'inputData = ReadInputData(someInputFile)' statement. 
Why is this statement failing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with a Python bytecode cache file. What is `read_input_file` and what do you have in `read_input_data` (note, two different names!)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That was a typo. I just fixed it. I import the read_input_data.pyc but unfortunately can't access methods within it. Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: `print` statement followed by indentation, after import statement ?

Comment: @anmol_uppal: fixed it.
All statements after the 'inputData = ReadInputData(someInputFile)' is ignored

Comment: @ChaitraRaghunath: if the code hangs on `ReadInputData(someInputFile)` then all we can do is guess. Something causes `ReadInputData.__init__()` not to return. Without source code there is nothing we can do to help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed [uncompyle2](https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2) to decompile my .pyc file to a .py file. It was making use of numpy and scipy which were not installed correctly. I reinstalled the required packages and it works fine now!